# c# usp folder picker subfolder

Tags: c#, uwp

Using the folder picker in a Windows 10 UWP app to allow the user to select a folder:

```
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();  
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =  Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

I can get a list of subfolder by:

```
  Task<IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder>> subFolders = SubFolders(folder);
  private async Task<IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder>> SubFolders(StorageFolder folder)
  {
      IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
      return folderList;
  }
```

When I iterate through the list:

```
  foreach (StorageFolder sf in subFolders)  
  {
       StorageFile f = await sf.GetFileAsync("something.dat");
  }
```

It crashes on the GetFileAsync, is this by security design or am I doing something silly?

All I get on the output view is:

The thread 0x2690 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure that *something.dat* exists in each StorageFolder? Aren't you getting 'File not found' exception?

Comment: Weirdly I wasn't getting an error in the debugger but if I put a try/catch around it, was too do with the thread I was using, thanks for sparking the idea, assumed it would just break on it

Comment: Using [`TryGetItemAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_TryGetItemAsync_System_String_) will help if you don't know if the file exists or not.